# Trace of a Matrix is positive

Tags: linear-algebra

I wish to prove that the trace of a matrix is positive. 
The matrix is defined as follows 
$B_+ = (B - \frac{Bxx^TB}{x^TBx})$ where B is symmetric positive definite.

Now Ive done the following:
$tra(B_+) = tra(B - \frac{Bxx^TB}{x^TBx}) = tra(B) - tra(\frac{Bxx^TB}{x^TBx}) = tra(B) - tra(\frac{(Bx)^TBx}{x^TBx}) = tra(B) - (\frac{||Bx||}{x^TBx}) > tra(B) - \frac{||B|| ||x||}{x^TBx}$

This is as far is Ive gotten. Is there anything Im missing to get to tra(B)>0

Comment: note: $tr(B\mathbf x \mathbf x^TB) = tr(\mathbf x^TBB\mathbf x) = \big\Vert B\mathbf x\big\Vert_2^2 \neq \big\Vert B\mathbf x\big\Vert_2$

Comment: Try expanding $\mathbf x$ in terms of the eigenbasis of $B$.

Comment: @Alex in eigen values representation or what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as stated, with $B\succeq 0$ there are some problems that break the OP's goal, e.g. with dividing by zero when considering $\mathbf x^T B \mathbf x=0$ when $\mathbf x$ is in the nullspace of $B$.  Also it technically isn't true that $tr(B^+)\gt 0$, only that $tr(B^+)\geq 0$
(For example, consider the cases when $B$ has rank one or rank zero.)

I prove the result **assuming that** $B\succ 0$
by application of matrix determinant lemma (for rank one updates):
$\det\big(B^+\big) = \det\big(B\big)\big(1+ \frac{-1}{\mathbf x^TB \mathbf x}(\mathbf x^TB)B^{-1}(B\mathbf x))$  $= \det\big(B\big)\big(1+ \frac{-1}{\mathbf x^TB \mathbf x}\mathbf x^TB\mathbf x)) = \det\big(B\big)\big(1-1\big)=0$

so $B^+$ is necessarily singular

to cleanup notation
$\mathbf y: =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathbf x^TB \mathbf x}}B\mathbf x$
$B^+ = B - \mathbf{yy}^T$

when we look at a quadratic form, for nonzero $\mathbf z \perp \mathbf y$
$\mathbf z^T B^+\mathbf z = \mathbf z^T B\mathbf z - \mathbf z^T\mathbf{yy}^T\mathbf z = \mathbf z^T B\mathbf z +0\gt 0$
by positive definiteness of $B$.
$\mathbf z$ lives in a $n-1$ dimensional subspace, and we know $B^+$ is singular, so it follows that $\mathbf y$ is in the kernel of $B^{+}$ and $B^+$ has signature of $(n-1,0,1)$, i.e. $B^+$ is a non-zero positive semi-definite matrix which implies $tr\big(B^+\big) \gt 0$

**addendum**
here's an analytic proof
consider the path
$B(\tau) = (1-\tau)B+ \tau B^{+} = B- \tau \mathbf{yy}^T$
for $\tau \in [0,1]$

now re-visit the matrix determinant lemma for rank one updates to get
$\det\big(B(\tau)\big)= \det\big(B\big)\big(1+ \tau\frac{-1}{\mathbf x^TB \mathbf x}\mathbf x^TB\mathbf x))= \det\big(B\big) \cdot (1-\tau)$
which is nonzero for $\tau\in[0,1)$

by topological continuity of eigenvalues this means that the eigenvalues of $B(\tau)$ are all positive for $\tau \in [0,1)$ i.e. $B$ has all positive eigenvalues because it is real symmetric positive definite -- and, essentially, apply intermediate value theorem -- so no eigenvalue can have 'crossed over' to negative without making $B(\tau)$ singular for some $\tau\in[0,1)$.  (A more careful way to do this is with winding numbers but I digress.)

Further applying continuity, this means at $\tau =1$, $B(\tau) = B^{+}$ cannot have negative eigenvalues and since it is real symmetric this means it is real symmetric positive semidefinite.

We merely need to show it isn't the zero matrix since for real symmetric positive semidefinite $C$, we know $tr\big(C\big)\geq 0$ with equality *iff* $C=\mathbf 0$
(easy proof:  $tr\big(C\big) = tr\big(C^\frac{1}{2}C^\frac{1}{2}\big) = tr\big((C^\frac{1}{2})^TC^\frac{1}{2}\big) =\big\Vert C^\frac{1}{2}\big \Vert_F^2$ and the Frobenius norm is positive definite.  )

I'd suggest finishing by noting that if we select any non-zero $\mathbf z$ where $\mathbf z^T \mathbf y =0$ then 
$\mathbf z^T B^{+}\mathbf z=\mathbf z^T B\mathbf z - \mathbf z^T\mathbf{yy}^T\mathbf z = \mathbf z^T B\mathbf z +0= \mathbf z^T B\mathbf z \gt 0$
so $B^{+} \neq \mathbf 0$ and hence has positive trace

Comment: You mean thath B+ is singular?

Comment: How can B+ be singular while being Semi positive definite?

Comment: you need to revisit the definitions of positive semi-definite vs positive definite.  There is a strong analogy with the terms "non-negative" and "positive" when referring to the real line.

Comment: B being singular can't be since it is a semi positive definite matrix as stated

Comment: So if B where to be positive definite then B+ would be positive definite?

Comment: I didn't give you a down vote. Sorry if I can't understand your proof. Could you elaborate on how B+ has such signature?

Comment: yes... I'm happy to add an analytic proof, which some people prefer to algebraic proofs.  The thing to keep in mind is the zero matrix $\mathbf 0$ is technically real symmetric positive semidefinite but we also know in general for real symmetric positive semi definite $C$ that $\text{trace}\big(C\big) \geq 0$ with equality *iff* $C = \mathbf 0$.  so what I did was show you have some matrix that is real symmetric positive semidefinite and not zero hence the trace is positive...  I take a lot of this for granted but it can blindside those who aren't as familiar.